# Accessing domain classes or spring beans from camel routes in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, apache-camel

I have a camel route file which I want to populate/configure based on certain database records accessed through Grails domain classes. However, I cannot seem to access the domain classes (or anything in the spring context) from MyRoute.groovy. Any ideas on how I can make that possible?

I tried the recommendations at [Grails: Accessing spring beans in the destory closure of Bootstrap code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574807/grails-accessing-spring-beans-in-the-destory-closure-of-bootstrap-code) but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Java RouteBuilder you can get hold of the CamelContext with the getContext() method. I assume you have the same method in the groovy builder.

With the CamelContext you can lookup spring beans from its registry.

MyType foo = context.getRegistry().lookup("mySpringBean", MyType.class);

Comment: You're exactly right. Unfortunately, it seems that this doesn't solve my issue though because at the the time I try to call the serviceBean it seems that it hasn't been GORMified yet and has no access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should take look at: http://camel.apache.org/hibernate.html

Please note, that you should add:

`...
ref('sessionFactory')
...`

to `beans` section in your `resources.groovy`

Comment: well, didn't try it as we don't have .hbm.xml files, so much assured it won't work. but this is very close to what we need ;)