# Grails: Dependency injection in regular groovy class

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

Let's say that I've got a BarService under grails-app/services and regular Groovy class 'Foo' like this under src/groovy.

```
class Foo {
  def barService
}
```

Are there any way to turn this into a Spring bean programmatically at runtime? Just to clarify, I want to get a reference to BarService injected into the barService field.

```
def fooInstance = new Foo()
magic-create-spring-bean-function(fooInstance)
assert fooInstance.barService
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574807/grails-accessing-spring-beans-in-the-destory-closure-of-bootstrap-code/614390#614390) on how to obtain the instance of the applicationContext. Wiring the bean properties can be done this way:

```
def ctx = ...
def foo = new Foo()
ctx.beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(foo, ctx.beanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME, false)
```

I would suggest using regular spring beans (maybe prototype-scoped) rather than this approach, though.