# Spring injection failure after update to Grails 1.2.1

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection

I used an older grails version, latest that was out in November 2009, and upgraded to 1.2.1 now. Unfortunately. I did not touch the app, checked it out of VCS. Now the spring injection does not work anymore.

I depend on external libraries (JmsTemplate, ActiveMQ, ...) and define all the beans in my resources.xml file. To test if spring is around, I implemented org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean on a service and i get the output at app startup:

```
void afterPropertiesSet() {
    println 'spring was here'
}
```

my service com.acme.JmsSenderService has the property:

def jmsTemplate

and the setup looks like this:

```
<bean id="jmsSenderService" class="com.acme.JmsSenderService">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

I tried the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574807/grails-accessing-spring-beans-in-the-destory-closure-of-bootstrap-code/614390#614390) and I get

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jmsTemplate' is defined
```

I deleted my old Grails version and I am stuck...

Comment: are you using the Grails JMS plugin or do you work directly with the JMS libraries? If the latter is true, please post your resources.xml.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't use the jms plugin, it doesn't do a very good job. But the question is not related to that. Also strings are not set: <property name="aString" value="hello world"/>

Comment: you might try to DSL-ify and use resources.groovy instead of resources.xml. The former definitly works in Grails 1.2.1

Comment: How did you update your project ? Did you try to run a "grails upgrade" in your project folder ?

Comment: @Philippe: I did a grails upgrade, yes...